# Getting invalid login details trying to login the API in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Models\User; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; 
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;

class AuthController extends Controller { 
public function login(Request $request) { 
if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) { return response()->json([ 'message' => 'Invalid login details' ], 401); }


    $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->firstOrFail();

    $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

    return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    ]);
    }

public function register(Request $request)
    {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
    ]);

        $user = User::create([
                'name' => $validatedData['name'],
                'email' => $validatedData['email'],
                'username' => $validatedData['username'],
                'password' => Hash::make($validatedData['password']),
        ]);

    $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

    return response()->json([
                'access_token' => $token,
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    ]);
    }

public function me(Request $request)
{
return $request->user();
}
```

But everytime I make a POst request with postman like this: http://127.0.0.1/api/login?email=luis@gmail.com&password=password I get: invalid login details.

I have tried changing the request for loginrequest but it doesn´t work.
Any idea?
Thankyou.

Comment: can you plz add your routes in question as well and which package you are using for token creation i.e. sanctum, passport etc?

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the email and password as query parameters instead of in the request body.

send the email and password as JSON data in the request body instead of query parameters

```json
{
  "email": "luis@gmail.com",
  "password": "password"
}
```

and change the route from get to post like `Route::post('you url')`.

query strings are commonly used in GET requests to pass parameters or filter data.

like `http://localhost:8000/search?category=books&sort=price`

Comment: Thank you for answering @spooor802. I have sent the email and password as JSON but it doesn´t work.